# PowerShell Out-File writes wrong data

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, powershell-ise

I want to put the result of my script into a new File therefor I am using `Out-File`.

My Problem is that when I run the script I have a different outcome inside my terminal then I have inside my new written file. It should be the same as it is inside my terminal tho.

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $outVar.Length; $i++) {
    $testOut = $outVar[$i].Line.Split("(")[0]
    $testIn  = $inVar[$i].Line.Split("(")[0]
    $testOut + $testIn
    $ConvertedStart = [datetime]::Parse($testOut)
    $ConvertedEnd = [datetime]::Parse($testIn)
    $loggedTime = New-TimeSpan -Start $ConvertedStart -End $ConvertedEnd
   # $loggedTime.GetType();
    $loggedTime | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\**\desktop\LDorado-LicenseTime.txt" -Append
    Write-Host "Licence got used for "  $loggedTime 

}
```

In my Terminal I see the correct log for example: Licence got used for 00:07:14.

As you can see I am trying to write the $loggedTime variable to the new file and this Variable holds the time values like 00:07:14, 00:03:34 and so on.

My file gets created and also populated but the data looks like this:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 36
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 2160000000
TotalDays         : 0,0025
TotalHours        : 0,06
TotalMinutes      : 3,6
TotalSeconds      : 216
TotalMilliseconds : 216000





Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 36
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 2160000000
TotalDays         : 0,0025
TotalHours        : 0,06
TotalMinutes      : 3,6
TotalSeconds      : 216
TotalMilliseconds : 216000





Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 36
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 2160000000
TotalDays         : 0,0025
TotalHours        : 0,06
TotalMinutes      : 3,6
TotalSeconds      : 216
TotalMilliseconds : 216000
```

I think thats because the datatype is a timespan maybe? But also I wonder why it differs from the Terminal log because the variable only holds the mentioned values (00:07:14, 00:03:34...).

EDIT: Ok so I noticed that Write-Host actually outputs the time like 00:07:14 but without it it looks like the data that is written to the file.. Soo write-host does some reformating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixxed it by myself. It seems that Write-Host reformates the data that is output.

By putting a `.ToString()` to my `$loggedTime` variable I actually get the desired outcome.

```
$loggedTime.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\**\desktop\LDorado-LicenseTime.txt" -Append
```